# Question closed because it was not in a busness enviroment, but i'm doing it for a company?

Tags: support, close-reasons

Now I'm just trying to understand the following close reason in regard to my question:

```
"Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow." – Sven
```

and this is the question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/717213/how-do-i-respond-to-a-get-request-in-c-asp-net

To me it seems that the question was closed because it was not in a business but I'm doing this for a company with some 70 employees so that makes it a business right? Or is there another reason as to why it was closed?  Just trying to understand, it's ok if there was another reason as to why it was closed but I want to know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a software development question. It *might* fit on http://Stackoverflow.com, but I consider it a bit too basic to just migrate it over there.

Please check with their help center to see if the question is welcome and if yes, post it there.

Also, please read our [help center](https://serverfault.com/help) before posting here.

Comment: Alright so it's not that it's not for a busines but that it's software and therefor off topic?

Comment: Yes, it's a dev question, not a system admin question.

Answer (score 8):

Your question was closed because it it not about **MANAGING** information technology systems in a business environment.

Your question looks like your're trying to learn about developing web pages with C# and other http technologies which are more topical on Stack Overflow.